# Track Newsletter Link Click with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pixel, event-tracking, click-tracking

I am partnering with an email newsletter to include some url links I'd like to advertise.

Can someone advise on how I might get "click" stats on these url links? The links neither redirect to my website/app, and are just links to, for example, a youtube video.

I've gone down the rabbit hole of Google's Campaign URL builder and Google tags, but am admittedly lost as a complete beginner regarding Google Analytics, tracking, etc, so *any* guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With Google Analytics, the only way you can track clicks within is if you leverage UTMs and drive traffic to a site or property that you own. I believe the UTMs might translate to YouTube account but, again, you have to own the video.

There are ways of leveraging Universal Analytics tags, in the form of pixels, that only measure when an email is opened (and the picture is essentially downloaded). But this doesn’t relate to clicks.

More than likely you will need to either use a dedicated email platform with built in analytics, or subscribe to an email analytics service. Google Analytics won’t really be of any value to you.